# Creating table from arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I’m looking to get a set of arrays and transform them into a table object (or something table-like).  In this case, I have a list of potential RGB values.
I'm not concerned about visualizing the 2 dimensional object, but just selecting and manipulating from it.

Here's what I start with: a group of arrays:

```
["Class", "R", "G", "B"],
["1", "166", "206", "227"],
["2", "31", "120", "180"], 
["3", "51", "160", "44"]
```

I then want to be able to select things based on either column or row.  I'm more concerned with ease of selecting elements rather than creating html objects (tr/td). I want to select and process data based on column identifier (R: "166","31", "51" -- for example), or by row identifier (1: "31", "120", "180" --- for example).

```
Class   |   R    |    G    |    B  
1       |  166   |   206   |   227  
2       |   31   |   120   |   180   
3       |   51   |   160   |    44
```

Here are my questions:
1. What kind of object am I looking for?
2. How would I create it from a series of arrays, where the key/table header is based on the first array (dynamic assignment - rather than hard coded)?

I appreciate your thoughts on this:

David

Comment: Javascript + multidimensional-array = Javascript Object (aka JSON)

Comment: What specifically do you mean by “selecting” (and ease of it)? Does the user click somewhere to select a row/column, does he input the values into a search form, …?

Comment: I wan't so much thinking about the end user gui, I just want a way to identify elements of the data in terms of two dimensions: class (1,2,3) and color (r,g,b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Benefit being that it is a reusable data structure independent of what the columns names are and you can keep your original data structure (array of arrays). You'll want to add any necessary sanity checks where necessary (making sure rows/columns exist, etc).

https://jsfiddle.net/z129o3v9/4/

```
var RGBData = function(arrayOfDataElements) {

    this.keys = arrayOfDataElements[0];
    this.data = arrayOfDataElements.slice(1);

    this.getRow = function(row) {
        return this.data[row-1].slice(1);
    };

    this.getColumn = function(column) {
        return this.data.map(function(row) {
            return row[this.keys.indexOf(column)];
        }, this);
    };

    this.addRow = function(row) {
        this.data.push(row);
    }

    this.updateValue = function(row, column, value) {
        var index = this.keys.indexOf(column);
        this.data[row-1][index] = value;
    };
};

var arrayOfDataElements = [
    ["Class", "R", "G", "B"],
    ["1", "166", "206", "227"],
    ["2", "31", "120", "180"]
];

var data = new RGBData(arrayOfDataElements);

alert("Row 2: " + data.getRow("2"));
alert("Column R: " + data.getColumn("R"));
data.updateValue("2", "R", "69");
alert("Column R after update: " + data.getColumn("R"));
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the second part of my question - how to arrange my data in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an array with objects:

```
var color = [
    { Class: 1, R: 166, G: 206, B: 227 },
    { Class: 2, R: 31, G: 120, B: 180 },
    { Class: 3, R: 51, G: 160, B: 44 }
];
```

and

```
var classIndex = {
    '1': 0,
    '2': 1,
    '3': 2
};
```

for the storage of the index of the array items.

Access via `color[classIndex[1]]['R']`

Working example:

```js
function colorType(cl, r, g, b) {
    return { Class: cl, R: r, G: g, B: b };
}

function addColor(ct) {
    color.push(ct);
    classIndex = {};
    color.forEach(function (a, i) { classIndex[a.Class] = i; });
}

function getColorColumn(key) {
    return color.map(function (a) { return a[key]; });
}

function updateColorColumn(key, values) {
    color.forEach(function (a, i) { a[key] = values[i]; });
}

function changeColumn(key, cb) {
    color.forEach(function (a, i) { a[key] = cb(a[key]); });
}

var color = [
        { Class: 1, R: 166, G: 206, B: 227 },
        { Class: 2, R: 31, G: 120, B: 180 },
        { Class: 3, R: 51, G: 160, B: 44 }
    ],
    classIndex = {
        '1': 0,
        '2': 1,
        '3': 2
    };

// display a single item
document.write('<pre>color[classIndex[1]][\'R\']: ' + color[classIndex[1]]['R'] + '</pre>');

// display the color array
document.write('<pre>color: ' + JSON.stringify(color, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// add a new color
addColor(colorType(4, 51, 102, 153));
document.write('<pre>color after insert: ' + JSON.stringify(color, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>classIndex after insert: ' + JSON.stringify(classIndex, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// get column B
var blue = getColorColumn('B');
document.write('<pre>blue: ' + JSON.stringify(blue, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// change blue
blue = blue.map(function (a) { return Math.min(a * 1.2, 255) | 0; });
document.write('<pre>blue after update: ' + JSON.stringify(blue, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// update column B with blue
updateColorColumn('B', blue);
document.write('<pre>color after changing B: ' + JSON.stringify(color, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// change R directly
changeColumn('R', function (v) { return Math.max(v * 0.5, 0) | 0; });
document.write('<pre>color after changing R: ' + JSON.stringify(color, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you!  How you use this is exactly what I was thinking. Really appreciate it.   How I get to the array with objects from my raw data is my next challenge.  I would want the keys dynamically added, rather than hardcoded. But that is another issue. Thanks for getting me started.